# Download multiple files one by one as listed in a datagridview (vb.net code)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, download, webclient

Vb.net studio is comparivily new to (as a hobby when I have time) me so I need some help. to simply download a single file is easy I do that by the following code.

```
 Try

            ' Make a WebClient.
            Dim web_client As WebClient = New WebClient

            ' Download the file.
            web_client.DownloadFile("TargetURLSite/MyFolder/" & "MyFile.exe", (Application.StartupPath & "\Plugins\" & MyFile.exe))


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Download Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try
```

Easy-Peazy...

But I now have a DataGridView column with file names of files I want to download. I thought that I could use a for each statement get the target file name from the first column of the DataGridView and execute the download function for each of the target files one by one but it dosnt seem to work I am lead to belive that its because the web client is stumbeling over its self still processing each download before being able to continue with the next.

```
For rowIndex = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

            'MsgBox("This cell is " & (DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("AppCol").Value.ToString))
            Dim TargetApplication As String = (DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("AppCol").Value.ToString)

            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Application.StartupPath & "\Plugins\" & TargetApplication) Then
                'File exists do nothing...
            Else

                'File dose not exist download to Plugins directory...
                Try

                    ' Make a WebClient.
                    Dim web_client As WebClient = New WebClient

                    ' Download the file.
                    web_client.DownloadFile("TargetURLSite/MyFolder/" & TargetApplication, (Application.StartupPath & "\Plugins\" & TargetApplication))


                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Download Error",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                
                    End Try
                End If
            Next
```

How do I fix this? I have a limited understanding of vb.net.

Comment: Perhaps [Downloading multiple files async VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382600/downloading-multiple-files-async-vb-net) has the information you want.

Comment: Do you mean that the app is stuck until all downloads are completed? That's because `DownloadFile()` is synchronous, so that procedure will *freeze* the UI while the files are downloaded. You can use the async version, `DownloadFileTaskAsync()`, add all the methods to a `List<Task>` while passing the Files to the async method and `await Task.WhenAll([The List of Tasks])`. -- This can be *dangerous*, though, when downloading from a Web resource: the Server may think you're hammering it and delay (or refuse to process) your requests or even ban your IP (at least for a while).

Comment: You can also use a `ConcurrentQueue` or a [ConcurrentStack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentstack-1) (there's a decent example on how to push work items to the stack and pop a limited subset for each iteration) or handle *manually* a [Partitoner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner) (*manually* since this class is commonly used by `Paraller.For` / `Paraller.FoEach` under the hood) and configure the partitioner when you create it (you have to run Tasks, though).

Comment: lol Jimmy its not going to ban my IP address its my own site running from my NAS

Comment: That's a configuration. The Server doesn't really *think* or get *offended* :) You may ban yourself from your own site. But I can try to assume that you haven't configured it like that :). Anyway, since access to disc is actually *sequential*, running parallel Tasks may not be that useful (if you store all files to the same local disc). So, an aysnc method that loops all files and calls (and awaits) `WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync()` would do. -- If the problem is that the UI *freezes*: it's not clear whether that's the problem you have.

Comment: the problem is that it will only download the first file in the list and halt everyother item in the list the thing i dont understand is that if i place a {msgbox("TargetURLSite/MyFolder/" & TargetApplication)} to display the file name that dose actually display correctly

Comment: Well, I don't know what's in the list or what files you have in the destination Directory. What you have to do is to declare the WebClient object outside the loop and dispose of it when the loop exits. Use `Path.Combine()` to build your paths, don't concatenate strings. Build the `destinationPath` and the `sourcePath`, then add `Console.WriteLine(destinationPath) Console.WriteLine(sourcePath)` before `DownloadFile()`. Put a breakpoint there and see what you're downloading (if you ever get there, that is). Note that RowCount also includes the `NewRow` object, if any.