# Download Multiple files using an array on C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a Downloader that will download 5 files from a remote server to the end users computer. Having issues with it. By using Function after Function, it downloads but, I want it to read a remote file and get the file names, put them into an array and then download them one by one from one function. This is being written in C# using Asynch.

My Code below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  // Start Downloads
    private void getPatch()
    {
        sw.Start();
        string patchlist = Settings1.Default.patchlist; 
        label1.Text = "Downloading";
        button2.Image = Properties.Resources.PlayButtonDisabled;
        button4.Visible = false;
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        Directory.CreateDirectory("WTF");

        string[] files = new string[6];
        files[0] = "libeay32.dll";
        files[1] = "libmysql.dll";
        files[2] = "libssl32.dll";
        files[3] = "ssleay32.dll";
        files[4] = "connection_patcher.exe";
        files[5] = "Config.conf";

        // Loop 
        foreach (var file in files)
        {

            var webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFile(Settings1.Default.baseURL + file, file);
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
            webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += OnGetDownloadedStringCompleted;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are the issues you're having with it?

Comment: it will not download the files given within the list, the list is a filename on each line

Comment: There is no "files given in the list" in the sample shown (`filelist` is just single string). Not very clear what you expect from this code. Answers to this post review bugs in provided code, for existing solutions see linked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747645/download-multiple-files-in-parallel-using-c-sharp.

Comment: That post doesnt solve my dilema therefore its not duplicate. file list pulls from a remote file, reads it then assigns the file names, at least that is the idea, only other option is to hard code the file names into the application. Which will result in another question on how to put them into an array.

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at your foreach(...) loop.

```
foreach (var url in filelist)
```

From the looks of it you'll actually be looping through each character in the string "http://somedomain.com/file_list", which isn't good.  Avoiding the 'var' keyword here would've caught this at compile time.

```
webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(Settings1.Default.baseURL + rFile), rFile);
```

rFile will actually have the entire contents of the file downloaded from the server, so the 5 lines together in a single string, which doesn't do us any good either.

After you get the contents from the filelist location, you need to split it up and loop through each line.

```
string rFile = webClient.DownloadString(filelist);
foreach (string singleFile in rFile.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None))
{
    await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(Settings1.Default.baseURL + singleFile), singleFile);
}
```

Comment: foreach (string singleFile in filelistlist.Split(System.Environment.NewLine))...

Comment: error - cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'

Comment: Sorry, should be good now.  Also corrected what string we are splitting

Comment: no errors but it is now downloading anything

Comment: not downloading anything

Comment: Time to set some breakpoints and start troubleshooting - I don't have any direct experience with WebClient so someone else may need to chime in.

Comment: thanks anyway plast1k

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of things right away that you may be overlooking.

First you are iterating foreach (url in filelist) but I don't see you using the 'url' anywhere in the loop.  The download string is all the same for each step in the loop.

Second you are using DownloadFileTaskAsync which will run asynchronously which also means all files are being downloaded at the same time.  It seems that you would get an error but just winging it here with looking I would imagine only the last iteration of the loop is actually working.  Either way, here's your code and what I think would fix it.

Also, it is good practice to hook up the event handlers before execution.

//Your Code

```
private void getFiles()
{
    string filelist = "http://somedomain.com/file_list"; 
            label1.Text = "Downloading";
            button2.Image = Properties.Resources.ButtonDisabled;
            progressBar1.Visible = true;
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            string rFile = webClient.DownloadString(filelist);
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
            foreach (var url in filelist)
            {
              webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(Settings1.Default.baseURL + rFile), rFile);
            }
            webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += OnGetDownloadedStringCompleted;

}
```

> //Assumed idea of what you're code is trying to do that will pull 1 file at a time.  I've added await / async to make proper use of the DownloadFileAsync task.  Hopefully this helps or allows you to see what you may have overlooked because I'm just winging this as a fix.

```
    private async void getFiles()
    {
        string filelist = "http://somedomain.com/file_list";
        //label1.Text = "Downloading";
        //button2.Image = Properties.Resources.ButtonDisabled;
        //progressBar1.Visible = true;
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += OnGetDownloadedStringCompleted;
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
            var rFile = webClient.DownloadString(filelist);

            //rFile needs broken up somehow since it is a string and not an array... unless you want the characters to be the array... which is odd.
            //So for dummying the code to work for now...
            var rFiles = rFile.Split(',');

            foreach (var url in rFiles)
                await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(Settings1.Default.baseURL + url), rFile);
        }
    }
```

Comment: each file in file_list is just the file name, ie: libmysql.dll with the baseURl being domain.com/files/ (not using my real domain here) so the url in the foreach makes no sence to me at all. also if they ar eline by line how would the , help?

Comment: and this doesnt download the files either

Comment: In your code you're not changing the download string value.  You're saying foreach (var url in filelist)  and 'url' isn't used.  I doubt the code I send you works since I don't know what will actually come back from filelist and what that string will look like.  Have you tried placing a break point in the foreach loop?  Do that and hover over the value url and tell me what you see.  Also, if you could just send me what the result string is from 'string filelist = "http://somedomain.com/file_list";'  I understand you're not sending your true url and wouldn't ask you to.

Comment: I also don't believe url is the best word for the loop but copied what you originally had.  You have a loop but in the loop it repeatedly asks for the exact same download.  So let's say you have 5 items in your filelist then you are still only downloading the same file 5 times at best.

Comment: I can definitely get this working for you as you intend but I just need more information.  What I presented as a resolution was just a push to show you a few of the things I felt were wrong.  It wasn't meant to be the fixed code that works.  I simply don't have enough to go on.

Comment: This is my current code, I am attempting to download 5 files but I want the progressBar to move continuously and not roll back on each file. A seemless download is what I am after.

Comment: Initial post has been updated

Comment: I hardcoded the files but it defeats the original intent and when it downloads the progress bar restarts on every file