# Create variable amount of strings

Tags: c#, winforms, variables

in my windows forms application I need for example a variable amount of strings. I am just using strings to simplify here. Actually I want to create a variable amount of Webbrowsers to access multiple URLs at once. So to use an Array isn't the answer in this case...

I tried to solve this with the use of a for-clause like this:

```
int amount = 12
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
   string variable_i = new string();
}
```

this didn't work because the variable, i in this case, is not being handled as a variable and it is only trying to create the string variable_i twelfth times.

If there is any way to accomplish that please let me know :)

Comment: What is the actual requirement? what would be the expected outcome of the snippet that you are looking for? I don't see any evidence for `I want to create a variable amount of Webbrowsers to access multiple URLs at once` in your code

Comment: Create multiple web browser instances and assign url to each at load time...

Comment: My aim is to quicky access multiple urls... It's all about speed. So I want to create for example 7 webbrowsers and make each individual one access a different url @un-lucky

Comment: Sounds like you probably want to use a Collection:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654013.aspx

Comment: your question somehow is ambiguous.

Comment: @dayan the problem here is that it can be up to 30 different urls but mist the time it will be just around 5.. So I don't want to waste processing power and therefore time on making 30 webbrowsers in advance when i only need 5...

Comment: Sorry for that... @Mr.AF I tried to not get to specific to make it relevant to other users as well... But feel free to tell me what I shall improve..

Comment: What do you mean by variable? As in, you don't know the exact number of webbrowsers you will need to create and therefore need a dynamic array?

Comment: Yes exactly. I don't know how many webbrowsers I need to create @NorianNyx

Comment: Are you wanting to create a "random" number of browsers or a "variable" number? If it's variable then you have some way of determining how many you want to start. You might also take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22748248/1454658 for a way to do this with async

Comment: @XaverXor Please see my earlier comment on Collections. They are what you want. Collections do not require a predetermined amount of memory and grow as they are added to.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you. My problem was solved by using `Collection` and the "marked as duplicate" (@un-lucky, @Grant Winney, @Alexei Levenkov) helped me to understand the (for me quite complicate) Microsoft Help provided by @NorianNyx .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sound like you're asking about an array that automatically grows as you add items to it. A [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) will do the trick. For example:

```
int amount = 12;
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
   strings.Add(new string());
}
```

Comment: I needed to use `Dictionary<string, WebBrowser> webbrowsers = new Dictionary<string, WebBrowser>();` since I wanted to add a specific named webbrowser but my question was answered by you greatly. Thanks a lot!