# Convert simultaneous downloads with WebClient to HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient, webclient

I have a WinForms app that creates several objects, each one has it's own WebClient and calls DownloadStringAsync on its constructor. When the callback DownloadStringAsyncComplete is called, the display is updated.
The main aspect that I want to preserve here is the ability to do several simultaneous requests, since each one takes several seconds.
How do I accomplish this with an HttpClient?
I could not await the GetAsync, but then, how do I know when each response arrives?
If I do await the GetAsync, then they will be executed one after the other and the whole process will take ages...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace RequestTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Requester> requesters;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            requesters = new List<Requester>();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                requesters.Add(new Requester(this));
            }
        }

        public void SomeoneCompletedDownload()
        {
            textBox1.AppendText("sample text");
        }
    }

    public class Requester
    {
        Form1 caller;

        public Requester(Form1 _caller)
        {
            caller = _caller;

            var client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += DownloadCompleted;
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("some-url"));
        }

        private void DownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            caller.SomeoneCompletedDownload();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download multiple files in parallel using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747645/download-multiple-files-in-parallel-using-c-sharp)

Comment: It takes 8h for one plane to fly from London to New York ... How much will take if you have 8 planes? ... seems like you are beliving that it will take 1h ...

Comment: @Selvin it does take less time because most of the time is spent on the server side.

Comment: @Eldar not really. My app does currently work but according to Microsoft, WebClient class should not be used, and HttpClient should be used instead. I'm trying to see how to do it in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found my own answer.
I just moved the request to an awaitable method.

The method itself awaits the response and calls the callback.

But when calling the method I do not await for it to finish.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace RequestTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Requester> requesters;

        DateTime start;
        int counter;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            requesters = new List<Requester>();
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            start = DateTime.Now;

            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                requesters.Add(new Requester(this, i + 1));

                // only one of the following 3 lines should be uncommented
                //requesters[i].RequestWeb(); // this uses the old WebClient (~ 12 sec)
                //await requesters[i].RequestHttp(); // this takes forever since requests are executed one at a time (~ 86 sec)
                _ = requesters[i].RequestHttp(); // <-- This is the way to go for my app. Dispatch the request and continue executing discarding the result. Callback is called in the same method. (~ 13 sec, consistent with option #1)
            }
        }

        public void SomeoneCompletedDownload(string page)
        {
            var elapsed = DateTime.Now - start;
            counter++;
            textBox1.AppendText($"#{counter}: Page {page} finished after {elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("N2")} seconds.\r\n");
        }
    }

    public class Requester
    {
        Form1 caller;
        string page;
        string url;

        public Requester(Form1 _caller, int _page)
        {
            caller = _caller;
            page = _page.ToString();

            url = "https://www.youtube.com/";
        }

        public void RequestWeb()
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += DownloadCompleted;
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
        }

        public async Task RequestHttp()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            caller.SomeoneCompletedDownload(page);
        }

        private void DownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            caller.SomeoneCompletedDownload(page);
        }
    }
}
```